# The verb был followed by another verb

Tags: грамматика, синтаксис

In [Цицерон](https://ilibrary.ru/text/1660/p.1/index.html) by Fyodor Tyutchev, we have these verses:

> «Я поздно встал — и на дороге
> Застигнут ночью Рима был!»

My guess is that it means more or less the same as: «Я поздно встал — и на дороге застигнули ночью Рима!».

My questions are:

1. Am I right about this meaning? Is there any difference of meaning between these two sentences?
2. What is this construction? How can it be generalized? Why is был in the singular (what is the subject?!) while застигнут is in the plural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> «Я поздно встал — и на дороге.
> Застигнут ночью Рима был!»

It means "Too long I slumbered, and Rome's night // Has overtaken me upon my journey!"

This is a paraphrase of this excerpt from Cicero's "Brutus":

> I must own, however, though I am heartily grieved that I entered so late upon the road of life, as to be overtaken by a gloomy night of public distress, before I had finished my journey

---

> *Я поздно встал — и на дороге застигнули ночью Рима!*

This is barely grammatical. I can probably imagine a context where it would make sense, but that's not how people speak and, in any case, that's not what the poem means.

If you want to use an active construct, you could use *я поздно встал, и на дороге меня застигла ночь Рима*.

> What is this construction? How to generalize? Why is был in the singular (what is the subject?!) while застигнут is in the plural?

*Я был застигнут ночью Рима* means "I was overtaken by Rome's night". *Ночью* here is not an adverb, it's a noun and the agent in the sentence. *Я* is the subject (and a patient, since the sentence is passive).

Comment: I see: I thought меня was implicit and застигнут was 3rd person of plural of present while it is a participle. Thank you!

Comment: Bruno, застигнут is singular, no particular person (я застигнут, ты застигнут, он застигнут...) It's a passive participle, not a 3rd person plural.

Comment: @SergeySlepov Yes, it is what Quassnoi explained so well. "I thought" meant: when I asked my question. After his answer, I understood that I was completely wrong as shown by my "while it is a participle". A posteriori my question was stupid, it is just that I was confused that the same form can denote two completely different things (passive participle and present) but with the context there is no reason to be confused.